# jaxb @ManyToMany @XmlID @XmlIDREF can't get the Refed objects into a the xml

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf

Hi i have a problem when i use a webservice 
I have an object User that contains many Roles.

When i get one User(Id:3) from my webservice that contains a role and that role containes many users(id: 3 and id 2). I got an error

Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Undefined ID "2".

I assume that this is due to the User with id 2 ain't in the xml.

My question is how do i get this user to be populated into the xml?

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class User implements UserInterface {

    @Override
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @XmlID
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IntegerAdapter.class)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

@Override
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=Role.class,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@XmlElement(type=Role.class)
public Set<RoleInterface> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}


}

@XmlRootElement()
public class Role implements RoleInterface {
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=User.class,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlList
    public Set<UserInterface> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you cannot unmarshall XML start starts with `<Role>` root element. You should remove `@XmlRootElement` from it. Please, publish XML that causes the problem and full exception stack.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `@XmlIDREF` the referenced object must also be mapped through some sort of containment relationship such as `@XmlElement`.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html